# how can i write this query with mongodb?

Tags: sql, mongodb

I want to write this query with mongodb

```
select   * 
from     tab1 a, tab2 c 
where    a.a_id = 2 
and      c.c_id = 3 
and      a.a_id = c.c_fk_account_id_created_by
```

I tried this code but didn't get a response:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('$and' => array(array("a_id" => 2), array("c_id" => 3))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have two collections, named tab1 and tab2 in the form of

tab1

```
   { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("58482a97a5fa273657ace535"), 
        "a_id" : NumberInt(2)
    }
```

tab2

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58482acca5fa273657ace539"), 
    "c_id" : NumberInt(3), 
    "c_fk_account_id_created_by" : NumberInt(2)
}
```

You will need an aggregation query with two steps, first, $lookup to the second table, and second $match on the proper keys.  Like this.

```
db.tab1.aggregate(
[
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from" : "tab2",
            "localField" : "a_id",
            "foreignField" : "c_fk_account_id_created_by",
            "as" : "c"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "a_id": 2,
            "c.c_id": 3             
        }
    },
]
```

);

This will give you an output like this

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("58482a97a5fa273657ace535"), 
"a_id" : NumberInt(2), 
"c" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58482acca5fa273657ace539"), 
        "c_id" : NumberInt(3), 
        "c_fk_account_id_created_by" : NumberInt(2)
    }
]
```

}

Good luck!

Comment: I like the answer from @Joshua and I'd suggest to use it. Just to show a different way... You get the answer also like this:

`db.tab1.find().forEach(
function (object) {
    var join=db.tab2.findOne({ c_fk_account_id_created_by: object._id, _id: 3 } );
    if (join != null) {
        // here are the matches 
        printjson(join) ;
    }else {
        // no match, nothing to do
    }
});`

Comment: MBushveld, that is actually an interesting approach as well.  It would at least be worth working through for the learning opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on just this type of query:

MongoDB Aggregation Framework for T-SQL Pros #3: The $lookup Operator
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mongodb-aggregation-framework-t-sql-pros-3-lookup-operator-finch

Essentially you are going to bring all documents from your second table into the results of the first table using the $lookup aggregation operator.  You can then use the $match and $group operators to filter and aggregate your data.

It will go something like this:

```
db.tab1.aggregate([
{   $match:
      {  "tab1.a_id": 2 }
},
{   $lookup:
     {  from: "tab2",
        localField: "a_id",
        foreignField: "c_fk_account_id",
        as: "tab2_results"
     }
},
{   $match:
      {  "tab2_results.c_id": 3 }
}
]}
```

The matching joined documents will be added to the base table's document as an array.  It acts as a LEFT join in that null values from the remote table are ignored and your base table document is still returned, only missing remote data.

Hope this helps!

Bill

Comment: Good call on matching a_id before the $lookup, I followed his example as closely as possible, but that is the right way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume tab1 and tab2 have 3 fields each as `a_id`, `aa1`, `aa2` and `c_id`, `c_fk_account_id_created_by`, `cc1`

## The query will be as follows

`db.tab1.aggregate([{$match:{a_id:2}},{$lookup:{from:'tab2', localField:'c_fk_account_id_created_by', foreignField:'a_id', as:'ccArray'}},{$unwind:'$ccArray'},
{$project:{a_id:1,aa1:1, aa2:1, c_id:'$ccArray.c_id',c_fk_account_id_created_by:'$ccArray.c_fk_account_id_created_by',cc1:'$ccArray.cc1'}},{$match:{c_id:3}}])`

Explanation of the above query:
As MongoDB doesn't allow to match from second table in the aggregation pipeline so we have to unwind the second table array and compare the value

`select   * 
from     tab1 a, tab2 c 
where    a.a_id = 2 ==> {$match:{a_id:2}}
and      c.c_id = 3  ==> (Cannot be done at first so it can be acheived as ) ==> {$unwind:'$ccArray'},
{$project:{a_id:1,aa1:1, aa2:1, c_id:'$ccArray.c_id',c_fk_account_id_created_by:'$ccArray.c_fk_account_id_created_by',cc1:'$ccArray.cc1'}},{$match:{c_id:3}}
and      a.a_id = c.c_fk_account_id_created_by ==> {$lookup:{from:'tab2', localField:'c_fk_account_id_created_by', foreignField:'a_id', as:'ccArray'}}`